# Model Builder - Selections Add Up at the End

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, select-by-attribute, select-by-location

I am creating a model so that I can help colleagues visualize the workflow I used on a problem.

My task was find all manholes in a specific area that connect to pipes >= 36". Simple enough, I did this outside of model builder and was able to generate the answer. When I put it in Model Builder and run it, the final solution selects all manholes and all pipes (collectively) in that area. That includes all pipes, regardless of size (1 inch, 6 inch, 12 inch, 18 inch, etc.). In the tools I used the derived data from the steps and used pipes that intersect manholes on a new selection. Not sure what to do!

Gravity Mains --> Select by Attributes * where Diamater >= 36

Pilot Boundaries --> Select by Attributes * where Name = NN05

Manholes --> Select by Location * Where Centroid is in NN05

The last selection is Pipes >= 36" that intersect Manholes that have their centroid in NN05

[image]

[image]
[image][image][image]

Comment: This picture doesn't help very much, the tools themselves have been renamed and as such we can't tell what each process is. What is "Select all >= 36"? What is the query? What is Gravity Mains? and its fields?

Comment: To compliment @MichaelStimson avoid renaming tools (yellow boxes), it's OK to rename the inputs and outputs but renaming a tool from the default name which describes what the tool is means other users have no idea what the tool is that is being run. Nor will you in 6 months from now...

Comment: Sorry about that. Please see edits to the post.

Comment: Is you query SELECT * WHERE diameter >= 36? Is diameter a numeric field or string field? (> and < do funny things with numbers as text).

Comment: SELECT * WHERE diamater >= 36.    It is a DOUBLE

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of your select by attributes dialog please. If your query starts with SELECT * that is proper SQL, so will run without errors, but doesn't actually select anything.

Comment: Pictures added to original post

Comment: You're selecting by distance your pipes with your manholes (all manholes in NN05) in the last screen shot, surely you want it the other way around.

Comment: Unfortunately neither selection works. I do not need the model for any other purpose other than to visualize my work flow. It will not be used by anyone, I just wanted to validate it. It selects all the pipes (80,000) and manholes (72,000) in the dataset, not the 300 manholes that connect to pipes >= 36". Not sure what is going on! Thanks though

Comment: Could it be something as simple as special characters in the Feature Layer name 'Pipes >= 36"'? Try renaming it to 'Pipes gt 36inch'.  If what you're trying to achieve is just for visualisation purposes then MS Word or Visio may be a better option for drawing the workflow.